# ISO 3166-1 country codes in DBpedia

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia

How can I get a two-letter ISO 3166-1 country code in DBpedia?  More specifically, I'm querying the [SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?iata ?country where {
  ?airport a dbo:Airport.
  ?airport dbo:iataLocationIdentifier ?iata.
  ?airport dbp:location ?country.
  ?country a dbo:Country.
}
```

I'd like to get ISO 3166-1 code instead of country name.  I couldn't find a predicate for that property, even though the codes are present in country infoboxes in Wikipedia. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `dbp:iso3166code`, but [it seems it's not set for a lot of countries](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+*+%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+dbp%3Aiso3166code+%3Fo%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Answer (score 4):

## DBpedia

The answer provided by @svick will probably be most useful one in the long run, but for the time being `dbp:iso3166code` is unusable.

However, I noticed that (apparently) all the country pages are the targets of redirects of this kind:

```
dbr:ISO_3166-1:DO dbo:wikiPageRedirects dbr:Dominican_Republic
```

Therefore, I can extract ISO 3166-1 code like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?iata ?iso3166 where {
  ?airport a dbo:Airport.
  ?airport dbo:iataLocationIdentifier ?iata.
  FILTER regex(?iata, "^[A-Z]{3}$")
  ?airport dbp:location ?country.
  ?country a dbo:Country.
  ?redir dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?country.
  FILTER regex(?redir, "ISO_3166-1:")
  BIND(REPLACE(str(?redir), '^.*ISO_3166-1:', '') AS ?iso3166)
}
```

## Wikidata

Update.  It turns out that Wikidata has much cleaner data, and as a bonus the query is shorter (although not immediately human-readable):

```
SELECT ?iata ?iso3166
WHERE 
{
    ?apt wdt:P31 wd:Q1248784 ;
         wdt:P238 ?iata ;
         wdt:P17 ?country .
    ?country wdt:P297 ?iso3166 .
}
```

[Click here](http://tinyurl.com/zbsw6hd) to see the query in action.